# Meteor js | Display Json in view via helper

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, meteor

Im struggling with an issue using Meteor JS.

I call an api wich return me a Json array wich look like the one returned on this url (I don't put the whole array here cause of the size): https://blockchain.info/address/12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX?format=json&offset=0

I call it server side like :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
       getWalletPreviousTx: function() {
       var url = "https://blockchain.info/address/12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX?format=json&offset=0";
       var result = Meteor.http.get(url);
       if(result.statusCode==200) {
            var tx = JSON.parse(result.content);
            return tx;
       } else {
            console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
            var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
            throwError("Couldn't fetch wallet balance from Blockchain, try again later !");
        }
      }
    });
}
```

And i retrieve it to my view via an helper in a specific template :

```
Template.wallet.helpers({
    addrTxs: function () {
      Meteor.call('getWalletPreviousTx', function(err, tx) {
         console.log(tx);
         return [tx];
      });
    }
});
```

The console.log in the helper actually log my Json array wich mean it have access to it.
Now the part im struggling with is to retrieve this Json to my view, i've tried a lot of way and none of them works, actually i have this in my view :

```
<template name="wallet">
    <table>
            {{#each addrTxs}}
                <ul>
                    {{> addrTx}}
                </ul>
            {{/each }}
     </table>
</template>
```

The part of the Json I want to display is the "addr" and "value" of each transactions :

```
"inputs":[
  {
     "sequence":4294967295,
     "prev_out":{
        "spent":true,
        "tx_index":97744124,
        "type":0,
        "addr":"1AWAsn8rhT555RmbMDXXqzrCscPJ5is5ja",
        "value":50000,
        "n":0,
        "script":"76a914683d704735fd591ba9f9aebef27c6ef00cbd857188ac"
     }
  }
]
```

Fact is, i never managed to display anything from this Json array in my view, even puting directly this in my view doesn't show anything :

```
{{addrTxs}}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Can anyone help with this ?

Thanks for reading.

----------------------- Edit ---------------------

I think the problem is more that my helper and template are loaded before the api call is finished (because the console.log appear in my console like 3seconds after my page is rendered). How can i make my helper wait until the api call is finished before rendering it in the view ? I use iron router.

I have tried to add a waitOn action on my route in order to wait until my api call is finished :

```
Router.route('/wallet', {
  name: 'wallet',
  template: 'wallet',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function () {
    Meteor.call('getWalletPreviousTx', function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
       Ready.set(result)
    }
  });
  return [
    function () { return Ready.get(); }
  ];
 },
 action: function () {
    if (this.ready())
      this.render();
    else
      this.render('loading');
 }

});
```

The above code with the waitOn action seems to work (i have no errors) but i don't know the way to display in my view the specific result from :

```
if(!error) {
   Ready.set(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are contained in *tx.txs*, iterates through that.

```
Template.wallet.helpers({
    addrTxs: function () {
      Meteor.call('getWalletPreviousTx', function(err, tx) {
         console.log(tx);
         return tx.txs;
      });
    }
});
```

---

You're right, you need to use the sessions variables with async call.

First, call method on created :

```
Template.wallet.created = function () {
  Meteor.call('getWalletPreviousTx', function(err, tx) {
     console.log(tx.txs);
     Session.set('tx', tx.txs);
  });
};
```

Helper should look like this :

```
Template.wallet.helpers({
  addrTxs: function () {
    return Session.get('tx');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried with your way, nothing happened in my view but if i console.log(tx.txs) it returns the array of arrays wich i need.
I think the problem isn't in my view code but more in the fact that the api call isn't finished when the helper is rendered in the view. How can i wait until the call is finished before loading the template ?

Comment: Can you provide the template you call with {{> addrTx}} ?

Comment: This is my template
<template name="wallet">
 <table>
            {{#each addrTxs}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{> addrTx}}</td>
                        </tr>
            {{/each }}
    </table>
</template>

But i really think the problem come from the fact that my serverside call isn't finished before my template is loading. I updated my issue with a waitOn function on my route.

Comment: We're getting closer, i did your way with the Session.get and now im printing something in my view :
<table>
                    {{#each addrTxs}}
                        <td>{{this}}</td>
                    {{/each}}
                </table>

This code display [object ][object ][object ]... in my view.
If i replace {{this}} by {{> addrTx}} it print nothing !

Comment: I don't know why you want to use the template {{> addrTx }} if it doesn't exist ? Instead, you can display {{ inputs[0].prev_out.addr }} and {{ inputs[0].prev_out.value }}

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicolasCharpentier for your help, i figured it out with your help, you got the bounty !